# Django unable to create project using command line

Tags: python, django, windows, django-admin, cd

I went through all the solutions but none of that resolves my issue. So while trying to create project using the startproject command on command line. I am getting an error.

Here is the series of steps that I have tried

```
1. Installed Python
2. Installed Django
3. django-admin startproject mysite
```

which gives me an error

```
CommandError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Himanshu Poddar\\Desktop\\mysite'
```

However django-admin is working fine though, which gives me a list of Django commands.

My Django version is 2.1.2 and I am using Win10.

### Edit

The command is working when I changed my directory to `C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar` and the file is successfully created but when I am trying same in any other directory I am getting an error.

Comment: Do you activate virtual environment?

Comment: No nothing sort of that. How do I do that?

Comment: Is there a traceback with the error? Can you post that?

Comment: No this error I am getting on command line when I type django-admin startproject mysite

Answer (score 1):

I experienced same issue. And it turned out to be issue regarding the python.exe file name.
I created virtual environment for python 3.6 and in the  envs/env_name folder the name of the file was python.exe instead of python3.exe
So I copied the python.exe file in same folder and renamed it to python3.exe. Now I can access the python using both `python3` and `python` commands in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows:**
To run `django-admin` command you need to activate python virtual enviroment.
To create virtual enviroment

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Then activate by

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

Then run

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

ALternative way:
Installing virtualenv through pip

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then create venv by

```
virtualenv venv
```

and activate by

```
. .\venv\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Himanshu Poddar\\Desktop\\venv'

Comment: Check python path variable or try to reinstalling python

Comment: reinstallation is not possible any other way? cuz I have many libraries installed already for ML/DL

Comment: So check python PATH .or check in cmd just run `python` see what output it  will show

Comment: This is what it shows """ Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. """

Comment: so try using `python -m venv venv`

Comment: Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Himanshu Poddar\\Desktop\\venv'

Comment: I don't know why it finds in /Desktop/ may be problem in PATH. Try this `pip install virtualenv` then `virtualenv venv`

Comment: still no success """ (venv) C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\Desktop\Django>django-admin.py startproject mysite
CommandError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Himanshu Poddar\\Desktop\\Django\\mysite' """

Comment: I have not a solution. But I can give a bit of advice to use PyCharm Editor. These must solve your problem

Comment: just createted my venv with name venv it just worked, ```python -m venv venv```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue and found the culprit (at least in my case): Windows 10 ransomware protection, specifically the controlled folder access setting. Turning that setting off and running "django-admin startproject mysite" allows the folder to be created. I turned controlled folder access back on after running the command.